# Prompt yes or no to repeat a command in a bash script

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I've attempted using "while" and "ask" without success but the whole goal of this script is to run a command or commands and then ask if you want to repeat the command again.

Example:

```
echo "adding a whatever... stand by..."
# prompt for yes or no to repeat the above command. If no go to the next command.
echo "Done adding."
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be an easier way, but this will work, at least.

```
#!/bin/bash

_repeat="Y"

while [ $_repeat = "Y" ]
do
        # Do whatever your tasks are

        # Prompt for repeat
        echo -n "Repeat? (Y/N)"
        read -n1 Input
        echo # Completes the line
        case $Input in
                [Nn]):
                _repeat="N"
                ;;
        esac
done
```

Comment: Ah! Using a variable as the condition for the while statement... Dang. I didn't think of that! Well that seems to have done the trick. I got it from here. Much appreciated!